# What is the meaning of the type "char" in C?

Tags: c, char, language-lawyer

Below are the quotes from C99 6.2.6.1

> 5. Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of *n* × **CHAR_BIT**
>    bits, where *n* is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. The value may be copied into
>    an object of type unsigned char **[** *n* **]** (e.g., by **memcpy**); the resulting set of bytes is
>    called the *object representation* of the value.

Q1. Does 6.2.6.1 p5 mean object representation is defined only when an objected is divided by char?(why should it be divided by **char**, rather than remaining itself?)

```
// illustrating for Q1
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  int var = 5; // var is not the object representation of itself
  char arr[sizeof(int)];
  memcpy(arr, &var, sizeof(int)); // arr is the object representation of var
}
```

> 6. Certain object representations need not represent a value of the object type. If the stored
>    value of an object has such a representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does
>    not have character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is produced
>    by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object by an lvalue expression that
>    does not have character type, the behavior is undefined. Such a representation is called a *trap representation*.

Q2. Why doesn't only character type cause undefined behavior when trap representation value is stored?(why is to read trap representation undefined behavior unless an object doesn't have **character type**?)

Q3. I guess generally we don't have to read trap representation. But if one try to read it, does 6.2.6.1 p6 mean any wider type(than char) should be copied in a char array as Q1 code example?

```
// illustrating for Q3
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TRAPVAL 0x12345678 // assume 0x12345678 is trap representation to the type int

int main(void)
{
  int var = TRAPVAL;
  printf("var: %x\n", var); // undefined behavior

  char arr[sizeof(int)];
  memcpy(arr, &var, sizeof(int));

  printf("var: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) 
    printf("%hhx ", arr[i]); // well defined
}
```

Comment: Just saying: prefer using `unsigned char` for this kind of reasoning.

Comment: "Does 6.2.6.1 p5 mean object representation is defined only when an objected is divided by char?(why should it be divided by char, rather than remaining itself?)" This question doesn't make any sense at all, and frankly it's not clear to me what you think the ordinary English word `representation` means here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I meant `object representation` which is defined in my first quotation.

Comment: Note that C99 is obsolete.  The current standard is C17 (a.k.a C18).  With that said, C17 also contains the specific provisions you quote.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I read the same two subclauses in [C17](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) but there seems no difference from my quotation. Can you let me know about "the specific provisions"?

Comment: I don't understand the question, @opol.  I already said that C17 contains the same provisions you quoted from C99.  My point is that you should not at this point be reading or referencing C99 unless to address a question specific to that obsolete version of the language.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry for causing unneccessary comments. It was because of my bad English. Now I understand what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1. Does 6.2.6.1 p5 mean object representation is defined only when an
> objected is divided by char?

No.  It simply means that the object representation is a sequence of values of type `unsigned char`.

> (why should it be divided by char, rather
> than remaining itself?)

The size of `char` (and of `unsigned char`) is the unit in which object sizes are measured.  `unsigned char` has no padding bits, so all its bits are significant to its value.  Thus values of type `unsigned char` are the basic units of storage in C's model of memory.

Note also that there are ways to access the individual bytes of an object representation that do not require copying the representation to an array, but the language specification chooses this definition to avoid forming a set of circular definitions.

> Q2. Why doesn't only character type cause undefined behavior when trap
> representation value is stored?(why is to read trap representation
> undefined behavior unless an object doesn't have character type?)

Trap representations are a characteristic of interpreting a byte sequence as a value of a particular type.  I suspect what you're missing is that C doesn't offer many choices for how you read a given object's representation: roughly speaking, you can do it as an object of a compatible type or as a sequence of [`signed`|`unsigned`] `char`.<sup>*</sup>  Only the latter alternative does not attempt to interpret the representation in question as an object of a type for which it is a trap representation.

> Q3. I guess generally we don't have to read trap representation. But if one try to read it, does 6.2.6.1 p6 mean any wider type(than char) should be copied in a char array as Q1 code example?

No.  You can examine the bytes of an object's representation in place by taking the object's address, casting that to type `unsigned char *`, and reading the bytes through the pointer:

```
my_type o;
/* ... assign a value to o ... */
unsigned char *p = &o;

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof o; i++) {
    printf("%hhx", *p++);
}
```

Do also note, however, that the "assign a value to `o`" part is tricky if the objective is to produce a trap representation in `o`.

---

<sup>*</sup>You can also read an object's representation as part of the representation of an aggregate or union that contains the object as a member, but that is not what the specifications are talking about here.

Comment: "Only the latter alternative does not attempt to interpret the representation in question as an object of a type for which it is a trap representation." I overlooked that when I asked. Thanks. But I wonder if this implies that [`signed`|`unsigned`]`char` type can't have trap representation. If so, it can't be read through the [`signed`|`unsigned`]`char` type which is the only way to interpret trap representation(I read trap representation very rarely occur at other SO question but I just ask for curiosity).

Comment: @opol, the language spec expresses more directly that `unsigned char` cannot have trap representations in C17 paragraph 6.2.6.1/3: "Values stored in unsigned bit-fields and objects of type `unsigned char` shall be represented using a pure binary notation".  Footnote 49 clarifies the meaning of "pure binary notation", and this does not afford the possibility of any trap representations because all possible representations are required to provide for all the values that `unsigned char` must be able to represent.

Comment: @opol, for `signed char`, C17 6.2.6.2/2 says "`signed char` shall not have any padding bits."  Together with the rest of 6.2.6.2, that precludes the possibility of any trap representations for this type.

Comment: @opol, default `char` is equivalent to one of the other two (implementations may vary on which), but either way, it cannot have trap representations.